# Widget x and y are doubled first time I add them to a view

Tags: android, view, android-relativelayout

I have a custom view where I programmatically add all the various widgets.
Since I really need a Absolute Layout, I'm using a RelativeLayout and setting the left/top Margins for each widget.

The very first time I add the widgets, their X and Y positions on screen are at exactly double the values I set.  Every time AFTER that (I remove all the widgets and re-add them) their X and Y coordinates are correct.

This is the loop I use to add them:

```
        RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.dashboard_view);
    view.removeAllViews();
    view.setBackgroundColor(dash.getBackgroundColor());
    Log.d(TAG, "updateUI: " + view.getX() + ", " + view.getY() + ", " + view.getWidth() + ", " + view.getHeight());

    for (IGauge g : dash.getGauges()) {
        View v = (View) g;
        Point size = g.getSize();
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(size.x, size.y);
        params.leftMargin = (int) v.getX();
        params.topMargin = (int) v.getY();
        view.addView(v, params);
        Log.d(TAG, "updateUI: " + v.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": " + v.getX() + ", " + v.getY() + ", " + size.x + ", " + size.y);

    }

    view.invalidate();
```

After the first time they are added, I dump their positions, I get:

```
dumpViews: Label: 48.0, 96.0
dumpViews: Level: 192.0, 206.0
dumpViews: Level: 288.0, 206.0
dumpViews: Meter: 96.0, 482.0
```

Note that ALL those values are exactly DOUBLE what the X,Y values logged during the loop are:

The next time I need to re-add all the widgets, all the X,Y values logged during the loop are the SAME during the add, but the dump afterward shows:

```
dumpViews: Label: 24.0, 48.0
dumpViews: Level: 96.0, 103.0
dumpViews: Level: 144.0, 103.0
dumpViews: Meter: 48.0, 241.0
```

These are the correct values.  Every time I re-add all the widgets again after that, I get these correct values.

So, why are they all doubled on just the FIRST time they get added to the view?

Comment: Doing more logging, I find that the very first time the widgets are added, they have .getLeft() == 0, and .getTranslationX() == getX().

The 2nd and later times, .getLeft() == getX(), and getTranslationX() == 0.

Answer (score 0):

So, after finding the getLeft() and getTranslationX() info, I fixed the problem by doing setLeft() instead of setX(), and setTop() instead of setY() - during my widget constructor.